# Flutter: DateTimeField manual editing problem

Tags: flutter, dart, datetimepicker, datetime-format

I have `DateTimeField` and there is strange issue while editing the date manually.

Here is the **display with default value**:

[image]

I selected month by double tapping and try to type `08` manually.

[image]

When I bring pointer at the end of month `12`, and pressed `backspace` to remove `2` from `12`. The month was changed to `01`.

[image]

When I press `backspace` in the end of year, to remove `8` from `2018`. It was changed to `0201`.

[image]

Here is the **code** of that field:

```
DateTimeField(
format: DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"),
onSaved: (val) => setState(() => _fromDate = val),
keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
onChanged: (DateTime newValue) {
  setState(() {
    _fromDate = newValue;
  });
},
onShowPicker: (context, currentValue) {
  return showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      firstDate: DateTime.now(),
      initialDate: currentValue ?? DateTime.now(),
      lastDate: DateTime.now().add(new Duration(days: 30))
      );
},
);
```

I have no clue, what's going on with this. Please tell me, what could be wrong?

**NOTE:**

1. Using picker for date selection works fine
2. I've `date` field in another page, it's in `yyyy-MM-dd` format, and it works as expected there.

Comment: Try with it https://github.com/jifalops/datetime_picker_formfield/tree/ce25e7024b9198e1a921b68a63b90574af7b0529

Comment: I would like to test it locally but would need some help from you to provide [a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and the output of you `flutter doctor -v`. Also, are you using any Flutter plugin?

Answer (score 0):

So I've tried the available sample that you've provided. I got a different behavior, I'm not able to edit the value manually. The date picker always open whenever I've tried to edit the form.

Here is the complete minimal code that I've tested base from your code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:datetime_picker_formfield/datetime_picker_formfield.dart';

void main() => runApp(BasicDateTimeField());

class BasicDateTimeField extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BasicDateTimeFieldState createState() => _BasicDateTimeFieldState();
}

class _BasicDateTimeFieldState extends State<BasicDateTimeField> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DateTime _fromDate;
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: DateTimeField(
            format: DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"),
            onSaved: (val) => setState(() => _fromDate = val),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
            onChanged: (DateTime newValue) {
              setState(() {
                _fromDate = newValue;
              });
            },
            onShowPicker: (context, currentValue) {
              return showDatePicker(
                  context: context,
                  firstDate: DateTime.now(),
                  initialDate: currentValue ?? DateTime.now(),
                  lastDate: DateTime.now().add(new Duration(days: 30)));
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

In the sample, I've used the current version of [`datetime_picker_formfield: ^2.0.0`](https://pub.dev/packages/datetime_picker_formfield) plugin.

Perhaps you can use the built-in [DateTime picker instead](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDatePicker.html).

Here is a sample demo that I've created for your reference:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.blue),
      home: MyWidget(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  createState() => MyWidgetState();
}

class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();

  Future<void> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: selectedDate,
        firstDate: DateTime(2015, 8),
        lastDate: DateTime(2101));
    if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate)
      setState(() {
        selectedDate = picked;
      });
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    selectedDate = DateTime.now();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Demo App"),
      ),
      body: ListView(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0), children: [
        Container(
          height: 100,
          child: FlutterLogo(),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10.0),
        InputDatePickerFormField(
          firstDate: DateTime(2015, 8),
          lastDate: DateTime(2101),
          initialDate: selectedDate,
          onDateSubmitted: (date) {
            setState(() {
              selectedDate = date;
            });
          },
        ),
        // Text("Selected Date: $selectedDate"),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => _selectDate(context),
          child: Text('Select date'),
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

This behavior means that you can not manually change the date select use your picker to change it