# How to handle DateTime overflow in Dart / Flutter?

Tags: datetime, flutter, dart

In a Flutter project I have an input form with a date picker. When a user picked a date, it is possible to alter the picked date by typing. I want to validate the form input and make sure the date input is a correct date.

Here is a screenshot of the input form:

[image]

Unfortunately, the Dart language `DateTime` object allows overflows. So, giving an input of `2019-13-1` (DateTime field is formatted like `yyyy-MM-dd`) and then validating that input will pass the validation, giving back a Date of `2020-1-1`. The 13th month, due to Dart Date overflow behavior turns into the 1st month, next year.

I know there is a Github issue for this already: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/11189

**Is there anybody who has a working solution to get around this issue?** Thanks for the help in advance!

Code for the DateTimeField is shown below:

```
                  ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.calendar_today, size: 21),
                    title: DateTimeField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Date'
                      ),
                      autovalidate: false,
                      format: DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd'),
                      onShowPicker: (context, currentValue) {
                        return showDatePicker(
                          firstDate: DateTime(2019),
                          initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                          lastDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year + 1),
                          context: context
                        );
                      },
                      validator: (value) {
                        if ((value.toString().isEmpty) || (DateTime.tryParse(value.toString()) == null)) {
                          return 'Please enter a valid date';
                        } 
                        return null;
                      },
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() => expense.date = value);
                      },
                    )
                  ),
```

Comment: Do you need the date field to be editable? Can't you make it uneditable?

Comment: Well, the problem is the DateFormField has no property to set editable to false. In earlier version 0.2.0 (current is 0.4.3) it did, but that property is no longer present.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that on the latest version of the [datetime_picker_formfield](https://pub.dev/packages/datetime_picker_formfield), `readOnly` is `true` by default to restrict from manually editing the values from the FormField. This was cited in [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/jifalops/datetime_picker_formfield/issues/73#issuecomment-569788367).

Here is a sample from the code that you've provided:

[image]

You can also check [this related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58247181/flutter-datetimefield-manual-editing-problem).